# Total angular momentum in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hamiltonian

Dos the total angular momentum, $J=S+L$, commute with the hamiltonian of a general sistem, with no particularities?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. There are plenty of systems whose hamiltonian does not commute with the total angular momentum.

For an *isolated* system the result does hold, but if there's any anisotropic interaction with the outside world (say, an external potential) then it will break.